# Updating an array in angular 4 after adding an element with splice?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a list in Angular displayed in table, I want to add an element in specific position.
I used

```
array.splice(index,0,element);
```

In the console everything is fine, the element is added at the correct position, but in HTML the table is not updated, the new element `element` is displayed in the position `index` and `index+1` ( the old value of the position `index+1` does not appear)

[image]

here is the function :

```
  addLineModified(id) {
    let index = this.detailsPieces.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
    this.detailsPiecesService
        .getDetailsPieceBylineModified(this.quotation.id, id)
        .subscribe((element: DetailsPieces) => {
            this.detailsPieces.splice(index, 0, element);
        });
}
```

these solutions give me the result in the picture,
the new element is displayed in the second and third position

PS: when I use push it works fine, but I have to add it in a specific index

Comment: can you share the content of .ts file

Comment: i edited the post , there is the function i used

Comment: can you please share all the relevant code (ts, html), not only the function?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the way you mentioned and it seems to be working fine(refer the demo below). The issue seems to be with the data you are receiving.

> .ts file

```
  export class AppComponent {
  arr = [1, 2, 3];
  val = 999;
  clickHandler() {
    this.arr.splice(1, 0, this.val);
    this.val -= 1;
  }
}
```

> .html file

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Index</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let index of arr"><td>{{index}}</td></tr>
</table>

<button (click)="clickHandler()">add at index 2</button>
```

You can check the working example here [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kiqvmp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: this solution return an empty array

Comment: @Gharbi check the demo, i tried the way you mentioned and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Splicing an element into the array does not change the Object reference hence not picked by change detection. You need a way to trigger change detection. Below should work

```typescript
   this.detailsPieces.splice(index, 0, element);
   this.detailsPieces = [...this.detailsPieces]
```

Using spread operator, the above will trigger change detection

Comment: it still give me same result

Comment: No, in the console, the array is sorted as I want

Comment: as @HimanshuSingh stated, I also have been unable to reproduce the issue, The code has just worked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ntydr

Comment: Thank you before, in the html i am using the index of each line (  <tr  *ngFor="let pieces of detailsPieces ; let i=index"> ),  it can causes the problem ?

Comment: I don't  think it can unless you pass `i` to the `addLineModified(id)` function

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior?